# Array in array for array_shift

Tags: php, arrays

I have several arrays from $ _REQUEST. For example: $ _REQUEST ['name'] and $ _REQUEST ['email']. That is, inside these arrays there is also an array. It turns out an array in an array.
Assigned them value

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
```

now I need to remove the first key with the value. For this I used **array_shift**

```
array_shift($name);
array_shift($email);
```

so i got rid of the first value. But, besides the name and email, there are others. It would not be desirable for everyone to write **array_shift**. How can I apply to all with one function?
thanx

**UPD**
For example $_REQUEST array:

```
Array (
  [name] => Array (
    [0] => 
    [1] => myName
  )
  [email] => Array (
    [0] => 
    [1] => myEmail
  )
  [other] => Array (
    [0] => 
    [1] => otherDatas
  )
)
```

I must get rid of these empty elements

Comment: Provide array structure and expected output for clarity.

Comment: Its better to have a example array for us to play :)

Comment: Do you want to shift all arrays in `$_REQUEST`? Then you could just loop over them: `foreach($_REQUEST as $r) array_shift($r);` Or do you have a list/array of all variables that should be processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple arrays in your request and you want to do an `array_shift` on all of them?

You could loop through your `$_REQUEST` and apply that function to all the arrays. Maybe like this:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as &$value) {
    if (is_array($value) && empty($value[0])) {
        array_shift($value);
    }
}
```

That will shift all arrays in your request and leave any other variables alone.

EDIT: Updated the example to only shift arrays where the first element is empty.

EDIT2: Added `&` to `$value` so that you can change the `$_REQUEST` variable directly.

Comment: @Гани Шахмурат I've updated my example. Now it would only remove the first element for the arrays that have an empty first key.

Comment: @ГаниШахмурат this answer you should use

Comment: http://main.xfiddle.com/e6bb1d36/shift.php
here's a sandbox with this code. something is not working.

Comment: That's because in that sandbox you print out the `$_REQUEST` again at the end. My code doesn't change the `$_REQUEST` variable. If you want to do that then you can use `&$value`. See my updated answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will clear empty values even if they are at any index.

```
$cleanArray = array();
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    $cleanArray[$key] = array_filter($value);
}
```

> Output

```
Array (
  [name] => Array (
    [1] => myName
  )
  [email] => Array (
    [1] => myEmail
  )
  [other] => Array (
    [1] => otherDatas
  )
)
```

Please note, it will also clear values like `null`, `(blank)` and `false`. [Example Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#example-6165)

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is create an array with the keys that you want from `$_REQUEST` and use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to get your subset.

Then use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to check if the value is an array and return that value using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove all values that you consider empty:

```
$keys = [
    "name",
    "email"
];

$result = array_map(function ($x) {
    if (is_array($x)) {
        return array_filter($x, function($y){
            return null !== $y && "" !== trim($y);
        });
    }
    return $x;
}, array_intersect_key($_REQUEST, array_flip($keys)));

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/433Dh)